# Асинхронные скрипты: defer/async

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Вот [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/external-script#%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%8B-defer-async) пишется о различие, ***defer/async***. Как я понял, то оба выполняются асинхронно.

**Async** - выполнятся, когда загрузится, не препятствуя, загрузке остальной части страницы сайта.

**Defer** - тоже выполняется асинхронно. + сохраняет порядок выполнения скриптов.

Собственно в чём вопрос: далее пишется что, второе отличие – скрипт с defer сработает, когда весь HTML-документ будет обработан браузером. Но почему, если он работает асинхронно и по идее должен также не препятствовать прогружению страницы, как и async. В итоге в конце написано: скрипт async.js выполнится, как только загрузится – возможно, до того, как весь документ готов. А defer.js подождёт готовности всего документа. Почему он будет ждать всего документа, если он асинхронный? Возможно я не до конца понял, что хотели сказать. Заранее благодарен за ответ.

P.S. также слышал, что о defer/async можно говорить не в контексте подгрузки скриптов, а в контексте исполнения кода. Тоже хотелось услышать об этом. Что и как.

Comment: Вы вопрос неправильно ставите. Надо не "Почему он будет ждать всего документа, если он асинхронный?", а "Почему он асинхронный, если он будет ждать всего документа?"

Comment: @Darth хотел бы услышать ваше мнение по этому поводу.